# How remove all rows with a specific string?

Tags: r

```
# A tibble: 4 x 1
   `134518d.g6`
      <chr>       
    1 134519dg6   
    2 134520d.g6  
    3 134521d.g6 
    4 134522dg6
```

This is part of my code. I want to remove all rows that contain .g and keep the rest rows (the first and fourth row in this code).

Tried to use this

```
df<-df1[! grepl(".g",df1$`134518d.g6`),]
```

but it didn't remove the unwanted rows.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this. The `.` has to be escaped, otherwise it stands for *any* character.

```
!grepl("\\.g",df1$'134518d.g6')
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

# and then use it on the data
df1[!grepl("\\.g",df1$'134518d.g6'),]
# A tibble: 2 x 1
  `134518d.g6`
  <chr>       
1 134519dg6   
2 134522dg6
```

Comment: you are a legend

Answer (score 2):

We could use `str_detect` from `stringr` package and negate (`!`) filter for pattern with escaping `.` with `\\`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  filter(!str_detect(`134518d.g6`, '\\.g6'))
```

```
 `134518d.g6`
  <chr>       
1 134519dg6   
2 134522dg6
```